# VS2010 Unit test “Pending” and the test cannot be completed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm using VS2010 (with windows 7).

Every time I try to run a unit test it stays on "Pending" and the test cannot be completed.

I tried to follow this [msdn instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I tried debugging test method (test view/debug selection), set breakpoints, but VS2010 indicates: the breakpoint will not currently be hit... I'm in debug configuration.

Any advice?

Comment: The issue is solved after Install SP1 for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have VS2010 and VS2012 installed on the same box you need to install SP1 for VS2010 or the unit tests sometimes won't work. ([SP1 available here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691).)

Comment: More details about this situation may be found on [the MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/09/08/not-able-to-run-unit-tests-when-visual-studio-2010-and-visual-studio-2012-are-installed-side-by-side.aspx)

Comment: That's the solution for VS2010 and VS2013, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a clean solution (right click solution and clean). And then do a rebuild. That should solve the problem.

Comment: I did it but it didn't help, still pending. I don't know how much time the run needs but I think it wolud be done in a short time. And still pending...

Comment: Still pending, and when I try stoping the test run, it dont't want to stop himself. I have to restart VS2010 to exit from this state.