# My unit test is always pending

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

First time attempting to use unit tests. I'm going to go through my steps:

1. Right clicked solution of my project I want to test in visual studio and clicked 'new project'. Then I selected Test > Test Project.
2. This gave me another project under my solution with a Test.cs file. I added the following to it:

   ```
   namespace TestProject1    
   {
   [TestClass] 
   public class MainTest
   {

       //Project1.MainWindow mw = new Project1.MainWindow(); //not used in test yet

       [TestMethod]
       public void MakeDoubleDate_Test()
       {
           string validMpacString = "1998,265/302010"; //When converted, should be 36060.430902777778
           string nonValidString1 = "nope,700/807060";
           string nonValidString2 = "thisDoesn't work";

           double validDouble = Project1.ConversionsUnit.MakeDoubleDate(validMpacString);
           double nonValidDouble1 = Project1.ConversionsUnit.MakeDoubleDate(nonValidString1);
           double nonValidDouble2 = Project1.ConversionsUnit.MakeDoubleDate(nonValidString2);

           Assert.AreEqual(validDouble, 36060.430902777778);
           Assert.AreEqual(nonValidDouble1, DateTime.Now.ToOADate());
           Assert.AreEqual(nonValidDouble2, DateTime.Now.ToOADate());
       }
   }
   ```

   }

My original project is called `Project1`. In my test project, I added a reference to `Project1`.

Now, my test shows up in the test view, but trying to run it it just is stuck on pending forever. I tried another person's project w/ tests and it did the same thing. Not sure what I need to do. Haven't had any luck snooping around google.

Edit: Here's some Debug output when I try running it:

```
The thread 'ExecutionUtilities.InvokeWithTimeout helper thread 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter.AbortTestRun'' (0x4748) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Agent: adapter run thread for test 'MakeDoubleDate_Test' with id '1bc08c40-ee7f-46e5-8689-8237cd3ffe4b'' (0x2820) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Agent: state execution thread for test 'MakeDoubleDate_Test' with id '1bc08c40-ee7f-46e5-8689-8237cd3ffe4b'' (0x1848) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Agent: test queue thread' (0x3ecc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
W, 18160, 8, 2016/03/29, 12:52:54.995, USERNAME\QTAgent32.exe, AgentObject.AgentStateWaiting: Proceeding to clean up data collectors since connection to controller is lost
The thread 'Agent: heartbeat thread' (0x4560) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2284) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x4484) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x43f4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3a50) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x4424) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Which continues until I exit out of visual studio.

Edit: Saw something about visual studio 2010 having problems w/o service pack 1. Turns out I don't have it. Updating now, hopefully it works.

Comment: Usually the pending state is during build before it execute the tests. Does building the solution finish successfully?

Comment: Yep! I tried rebuilding both the main project and test project separately, and the entire solution, all of which succeeded. It's just the one test in there right now.

Comment: Updated my post w/ some debug info.

Comment: What is the MainWindow member?

Comment: Are there other tests visible in the test explorer?

Comment: It's a wpf app. MainWindow is just the main window that appears when the app starts up.

Comment: @StingyJack Nope, just the one I coded in (which is the only one in the file at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my `visual studio 2010` to `service pack 1` solved the issue and my tests run correctly now.

Got the idea to do so from this link: [VS2010 Unit test “Pending” and the test cannot be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686360/vs2010-unit-test-pending-and-the-test-cannot-be-completed)